# Does the first amendment protect business owners from being forced to work for protected classes?

Tags: united-states, bill-of-rights

Certain [classes are protected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_class) from discrimination in the United States.

The intersection of the right to freedom of speech and being free from discrimination is getting [more attention due to some recent cases](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702304795804579101343898974538)

> Jonathan and Elaine Huguenin, the owners of Elane Photography, who argued that they shouldn't be forced to create images that tell "a positive and approving" story about a ceremony they find objectionable.
>
> Mr. Phillips [...] wrote that his refusal to bake cakes for same-sex weddings is not motivated by a "hatred of gays" but rather "a desire to live my life in obedience to [God] and His Word."
>
> Ms. Stutzman countersued Washington in August, claiming the U.S. and state constitutions protect her from being forced to perform actions contrary to her "religious beliefs and her conscience."

**Can the government compel you (if you run a business) to perform work for protected classes that you objec to on first amendment grounds?** (For example, could a Jewish bakery be forced to bake an [Adolf Hitler cake](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/28269290/)?)

Comment: National Origins would possibility be the protected class for the example above. I am aware that the [first amendment](http://www.outsidethebeltway.com/texas-cheerleader-who-refused-to-cheer-rapist-loses-in-court/) has limits, I am just wondering if they overrule protected class legislation.

Comment: That's the problem with the word freedom.  Denying someone service based on how they were born is discrimination.  Denying someone the ability to deny service to another is discrimination.
Is it discrimination to deny someone the freedom to discriminate?

Comment: I will refer you to my answer to a similar question (rather than answering this one directly). http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/are-clergy-required-to-perform-interracial-and-or-same-sex-marriages-in-the-unit/1249#1249 Basically, the U.S. government can't force you do say/do something in this kind of situation. It can only prevent you from saying/doing the "wrong" thing.

Comment: What do you have in mind? You might want to focus your question to be about the specific issue you are actually concerned about. The Amendments cover a very very broad prohibition against enacting certain types of laws. What laws would actually be infringing is also another very large and complex topic. So your question is virtually impossible to answer in this format besides being kind of circular. If you have a specific action you are concerned about, I would suggest asking that.

Comment: In general the power of the government to prevent businesses from discriminating in their customer selection was established by the court challenges to the Civil Rights Act of 1964.

Comment: @RobertCartaino, Bobson's answer was the sort of info I was looking for. I am only interested in private businesses that perform creative work, and whether they can be compelled (by force of law through penalities, etc.) to perform jobs that conflict with their freedom of religion or speech. SCOTUS cases would be the most useful. Is there a better way to phrase the question?

Comment: user1873, The crux of your question seemed somewhat circular to me. "Can the government restrict things they are prohibited from restricting you from." I was only suggesting focusing on the specific case, as in: "how was the government able to restrict this <specific right>?"

Comment: @user1873  The correct answer to this question is as follows:  As soon as SCOTUS rules in Elaine Photography, we will know the answer.

Comment: All these good answers, and 1 upvote. Apparently people think the question is good enough to warrant an answer, but not good enough to upvote.

Comment: Your Jewish bakery example is disingenuous.  A Jewish bakery cannot refuse to sell me, a goy, a cake.  But I can't force them to make a Hitler cake.  If you're in the business of photographing weddings, then you can't refuse to photograph a wedding without legitimate reason such as scheduling conflicts.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore, I don't see how my example question can be disingenuous, as i don't know the answer to that question. You though seem to say that you do know the answer, and that you can as a business choose not to bake a Hitler cake, but cannot choose to not photograph a gay wedding. This seems odd considering that bakeries are in the businees of making cakes. Could a bakery refuse to bake a cake for a gay couple that said "happy aniversarry Pete, Love your husband."  How would this be different than the Hitler B-day cake?

Answer (score 6):

While Bobson gave an excellent answer, I am going to step out and give a slightly different one, bearing in mind the exct wording of the question

**The constitutionality of the principle of government forcing businesses to not discriminate against protected minorities was established during the legal challenges to the Civil Rights Act of 1964.** The act forced business owners to serve black customers, despite whatever personal views they had on the matter, and the supreme court found that it was constitutional. This is the answer to the question as asked. i.e. whether 'business owners can be forced to work for protected classes'.

My understanding is that there is a slightly different take on the 'gay weddings' question - namely that the objection is to the work performed, not the customer it is performed for. The business might claim that they will not do work for gay weddings, whether the customer is gay or straight (while perhaps agreeing to do other work for customers of any sexual orientation), and that this is more akin to a restaurant owner declining to serve fried fish to any kind of customer than to a restaurant refusing to serve a coloured person. This matter has yet to be decided by the courts.

Comment: A very good distinction, and almost certainly what it's going to hinge on.  "I don't do that type of event" seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to say, even if it's referring to a discriminatory class (DJ saying "I don't do Bar Mitzvah parties", for instance).  However, the *level of involvement* matters too - if the bakery won't produce a cake for the event, even if they don't need to attend, that's very different from the band which is being asked to play music during it.

Comment: +1 This an interesting way to frame the argument, and why I was specifically interested in **creative work**. For certain professions I could understand, but for ohers the argument seems weak (aranging flowers, decorating a cake). Are there more SCOTUS decisions than those listed under the protected classes?

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, this is exactly the question that Elaine Photography is going to decide. And, until the court actively overrules the lower court decision, the answer is, in theory "Yes, they can."

The facts of the case are simple enough - when the religious right to "practice the [free exercise thereof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Exercise_Clause)" conflicts with the rules required of a place of [public accommodation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_accommodations), which "right" wins?

As a pastor who fears being compelled to perform same-sex marriages, I certainly hope I won't be forced to compromise my beliefs - but I am also aware of the incident in which [a Louisiana Justice of the Peace was fired for simply requesting that an interracial couple go to another JP for their wedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Louisiana_interracial_marriage_incident).  While one will probably make the case that there is a difference between an officer of the court and a pastor, one should remember that in my home state of Virginia, wedding officiants of any type are acting as officers of the court.  When I got my license to perform wedding ceremonies, I had to take an oath to the state.

Am I nervous?  Heck yeah.

Comment: JP's are very different than pastors.  Though I agree that I can see at least 4 JotSC voting to compel clergy to perform them... I think immediately following that vote they should all be hung for treason for failure to uphold the constitution that they pledged to do.

Comment: @Chad - JotSCs at one time or another voted for Dredd vs Scott, for the claim that human right to life can be trumped by convenience, and for the fact that forcing me to enter into a business transaction I don't wish to enter is fully legal. If your line of thinking held, most SCOTUSes would be called David Carradine

Comment: @DVK - I Think that if we did that then perhaps we would not have some many 5-4 votes on what should be a straight 9 vote smack down of congress and the president that signed the legislation.

Answer (score 3):

The rights / protected classes you are talking about are equal protection issues, which fall under the 14th Amendment. (Summarized as equal protection under the law). The Supreme Court decided in 1883 that the Civil Rights Act of 1875, which prohibited private businesses from discriminating against African Americans was unconstitutional because "The Fourteenth Amendment ... is prohibitory upon the States ... Individual invasion of individual rights is not the subject matter of the amendment" -Civil Rights Cases, 109 U.S. 3 (1883)

The Civil Rights Act of 1964 ultimately achieved what the 1875 Act could not. This Act used the Legislative power to control interstate commerce to regulate businesses as oppose to the Equal Protection Clause of the 14th Amendment, and was upheld by the Supreme Court. Congress may only use the Commerce Clause when there is a significant impact upon interstate commerce.

The decision was again reaffirmed recently in the United States v. Morrison, 529 U.S. 598 (2000). This case challenged the validity of 42 U.S.C.S. § 13981, which was a law Congress enacted that provided a federal civil remedy for the victims of gender-motivated violence. 
A woman that was attacked wanted the civil remedy due to her for this. The attacker did not want to pay and appealed, alleging that Congress didn't have the right to enact such a law. The Court of Appeals for the Fourth Circuit declared the law unconstitutional. They found that there was no substantial influence on commerce, so Congress could not use the commerce clause, and they also could not use the Fourteenth Amendment because of the precedent the Court established in the Civil Rights Act of 1875. The Supreme Court reviewed the case and affirmed the decision of the Fourth District.

Therefore the 14th Amendment still doesn't apply unless the conduct is considered a state action. To be a state action one of the following criteria must apply:

- The individual is employed by the government and acting as a government officer. In other words if the individual is acting in an official capacity, whether or not the conduct is authorized by law. (Gov't Officer Exception)
- If the individual/business is performing a function that has been traditionally done exclusively by the government. (Public Function Excception)
- If the government has expressly authorized, encouraged, or facilitated the unconstitutional conduct. (Entanglement Exception)

The only Amendment that applies directly to the people is the 13th Amendment, which outlaws the practice of slavery throughout the United States.

Comment: I believe you omit a significant piece of information, which is that the constitutionality of restricting the ability of private businesses to discriminate against customers was UPHELD during the challenges against the 1964 Civil Rights act, reversing the earlier decisions with regard to the 1875 Civil Rights act.

Comment: Someone visiting this site and reading this answer might be interested to know what `United States v. Morrison` was about.  I'm certainly interested in it.   A brief summary of that might strengthen your answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth Sorry about that, I didn't get a chance to get to that. The 1964 Civil Rights Act was indeed upheld, but only because Congress has the authority to regulate interstate commerce. The decisions that the Court made regarding the 1875 version were never reversed. The Fourteenth Amendment is still only applicable to the government. Which leads me to the next point.

Comment: @SamIam The United States v. Morrison was in regards to 42 U.S.C.S. § 13981, which was a law Congress enacted that provided a federal civil remedy for the victims of gender-motivated violence.

Comment: A woman that was attacked wanted the civil remedy due to her for this. The attacker did not want to pay and appealed, alleging that Congress didn't have the right to enact such a law.The Court of Appeals for the Fourth Circuit declared the law unconstitutional. They found that there was no substantial influence on commerce, so Congress could not use the commerce clause, and they also could not use the Fourteenth Amendment because of the precedent the Court established in the Civil Rights Act of 1875. The Supreme Court reviewed the case and affirmed the decision of the Fourth District.

Comment: @pAvEmEnT put that in your anser

Comment: Nice revision.  Much clearer now. Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

The government can't *force* a business to act, but they can punish them for not acting.  The threat of punishments (which may range from fines, to having to pay damages, up to being arrested or forced to shut down) may **compel** the business to act (in the sense of "apply pressure to act"), but it's always the option of the owner to accept those punishments instead of changing their behavior.

As to the question of whether the government can punish a business which refuses service to a protected class based on a religious position, that's still an open question, and will vary state-by-state.  For example, in California there's a state Civil Rights called the Unruh Civil Rights Act [which prohibits arbitrary discrimination](http://www.legalzoom.com/us-law/equal-rights/right-refuse-service).

Until it gets to the Supreme Court, there's no way to provide a more definitive answer.

Comment: @DVK - Possibly. It depends on whether you read `compelling` as having *successfully* forced the action or not.  I'll clarify the wording a bit.

Comment: how is punishing someone for not acting not the same as forcing them to act?  if you get a fine for driving fast, that is govt forcing you to drive slowly

Comment: @amphibient - See [Civil Disobedience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_disobedience) for the best example.  Effectively, the government can't actually *make* someone perform their service, short of getting someone to stand there and physically move the owner/operator through the motions.  There's always the option for them to refuse.

Comment: @Bobson but that would mean slavery doesn't violate the involuntary servitude clause because you can't force someone to pick cotton if all you do is punish them after the  fact by whipping them.